# Types for update Record function with deep path and callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create an update function that updates deep values in record. I have overloaded variants for paths of different depths.

I can't seem to figure out how to properly type the callback function used on the value to be updated.

```
interface Test {
    foo?: { bar: number }
}
const input: Test = { foo: { bar: 1 } }

update(input, 'foo', 'bar')(v => v + 1)
```

When I use the function, it tells me that "Object(v) is of type unknown".

But for example I have similar set function, that's defined almost the same, but it gets typed properly when used like this:

```
set(input, 'foo', 'bar')(2)
```

Here's my function

```
type UpdateFn<T> = (value: T) => T
export function update<T extends Record<string, any>, K1 extends keyof T>(
    record: T | undefined,
    key1: K1
): (callback: UpdateFn<NonNullable<T[K1]>>) => T
export function update<
    T extends Record<string, any>,
    K1 extends keyof T,
    K2 extends keyof NonNullable<T[K1]>
>(
    record: T | undefined,
    key1: K1,
    key2: K2
): (callback: UpdateFn<NonNullable<T[K1][K2]>>) => T

export function update<
    T extends Record<string, any>,
    K1 extends keyof T,
    K2 extends keyof NonNullable<T[K1]>
>(
    record: T | undefined,
    key1: K1,
    key2?: K2
): (
    callback:
        | UpdateFn<NonNullable<T[K1]>>
        | UpdateFn<NonNullable<T[K1][K2]>>
) => T | undefined {
    return callback => {
        if (record === undefined) return record

        if (key2 === undefined) {
            const value = get(record, key1)
            if (value === undefined) return record
            return set(record, key1)(callback(value))
        } else {
            const value = get(record, key1, key2)
            if (value === undefined) return record
            return set(record, key1, key2)(callback(value))
        }
    }
}
```

Set (working correctly):

```
export function set<
    T extends Record<string, any>,
    K1 extends keyof T,
    K2 extends keyof NonNullable<T[K1]>
>(record: T | undefined, key1: K1, key2: K2): (value: T[K1][K2]) => T
```

Comment: Do you really need the depth? e.g. can't you reduce `update(input, 'foo', 'bar')(v => v + 1)` to `update(input.foo, 'bar')(v => v + 1)`?

Comment: Yes I need the depth, because the function needs to return the whole updated input object, nut just input.foo. It wouldn't be easily composable otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm just trying to address the typings and not the implementation, your second overload should probably be something like this:

```
export function update<
    T extends Record<string, any>,
    K1 extends keyof T,
    K2 extends keyof NonNullable<T[K1]>
>(
    record: T | undefined,
    key1: K1,
    key2: K2
): (callback: UpdateFn<NonNullable<NonNullable<T[K1]>[K2]>>) => T
```

That extra `NonNullable` in there makes sure that you're talking about the type of `record[key1][key2]` if `record` and `record[key1]` are both defined/non-null.  There may be other, more general or cleaner ways to do the typings for `update()`, but this at least fixes the issue you're seeing:

```
update(input, 'foo', 'bar')(v => v + 1); // okay
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=50&ssc=1&pln=50&pc=40#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDYEBiA7APAFQHxQF4oAKAN0QBsBXCALimwEpD9sAoNiADzAHsAnYFABmVdAGNgAS17ooVBMgg4o3FOngBnKACUI4gfEybg-KegDmAGiiJ0IXDYDSARlVd1WqAGsIIXsIMuMRsUGFQ-PqG9NhQAD7yGhDC5hDwVqHhviAu9K5sjPTE4pQUAEaI4t70cEgoGJgAcrKNVBQUiGUUytgA2q4Auri4zASsnDwCQqIS0rLyiiiYmWGxahAa2noG-EYmZpY2dg4Z4VCu7p7a2QEMp+FOAEyXG143gc3ore2d3Tj9LiGbGCKwiUV2MXiiXgyVS6VB2Vy5xc9zC2UeeUeBSKJXaFSqNUWaCwn2+HS6ylJbXJfz6g1w-UeQxGLAYHG4fEEIjEkhkcgUdWUoLWHleW3Be1M5mstnsjlBF3Wmx8flu2FR52eSreqo+LWpvx6AKBILOkR28EhCTEMJS6DSGsReRRCL8jwA-JjsSRQWdceVKtVfWdwglakoGlSfhT-vTcMGQ1Dw-USfro7TjYzmaDRqwoTbYfb4FAAN6gyLAKj8OT+-HeVllxNhKSBYjmwyEAhEAt2tLMCtVuTt3YcJtQFskdGd7tJXvwZiNsfhAzoExQcjUaBECwQYBtiU2RGMBMhidkSg0afQwt9sGV6tgi0ns27wdQTS7-cWw9+FyMYqlHW56bowx5jgAvqoFAfqWz7LrIa4bpe26fsO6QqjkP4gI8YFLs2rZIVuXbXnO-avg+aFwWEA4Ph+e5oVhKIYThAF4oGwE0KBJ7gaCPE8Ww5goPwwiVNA2AQGui5hMIvC8J6pZQBU-D0OgVAALZlBA-BQHxbArmu5hgFQwAxBJQhECWIiyfQllKfQbiQfxApKMQhnGTYADkMm8B5nlKR5-6kKyQUANRQH+QA)